# Получение геолокации в Telebot python

Tags: python, telebot

Нужно получать геолокацию пользователя при нажатии на кнопку "отправить".
Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку "отправить" в самом чате бота ему должно высветиться данное окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если пользователь отправляет геолокацию через вложение, пользователю не чего не выводиться (то-есть нужно отлеживать геолокацию и нажатие на кнопку одновременно)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько мой ответ актуален. Фрагмент кода, запрашивающий геолокацию с помощью Inline-кнопок:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["geo"])
def geo(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id, "Нажмите на кнопку, чтобы передать свое местоположение боту.",
        reply_markup=keyboard)
```